# Sort this list on the basis of date(in increasing order) (in python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
a = [{"date":[14,2,2020],"stockValue":-0.57357144},{"date":[9,2,2020],"stockValue":-0.66407406},{"date":[10,2,2020],"stockValue":-0.62166667}]
```

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
a = [{"date":[14,2,2020],"stockValue":-0.57357144},{"date":[9,2,2020],"stockValue":-0.66407406},{"date": [10,2,2020],"stockValue":-0.62166667}]

print(sorted(a, key=lambda x: datetime(year=x["date"][2], month=x["date"][1], day=x["date"][0])))
```